# Template operator[] overloading strange C2676

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to overload the [int] operator in a templated class, but I always get a C2676 error followed by a visual studio E0349 "no operator [] matches these operands WMSTR [ int ]"

My template class:

```
template <typename T, unsigned int N>
class MyString{
    public:

    // ... Non relevant tested code

    template<typename T, unsigned int N>
    T& operator[](int index) {
        // Assert index size
        SLOW_ASSERT(index >= 0 && index < N);
        // Return current value
        return m_buffer[index];
    }

    template<typename T, unsigned int N>
    const T& operator[](int index) const {
        // Assert index size
        SLOW_ASSERT(index >= 0 && index < N);
        // Return current value
        return m_buffer[index];
    }

    private:
    T m_buffer[N];
}
```

SLOW_ASSERT(...) is just a wrapper to assert(...)

Content of main:

```
#include "path_to_template.h"
typedef MyString<wchar_t, 24> WMSTR;

int main(void){
   WMSTR str = L"Test";
   str[0] = L'X'; // <-- Error here

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring both the `operator[]` as function template, their template parameters can't be deduced and then calling fails.

Making them non-template should work fine; I suppose you just want to refer to template parameter `T` and `N` of class template `MyString` in `operator[]`.

```
T& operator[](int index) {
    // Assert index size
    SLOW_ASSERT(index >= 0 && index < N);
    // Return current value
    return m_buffer[index];
}

const T& operator[](int index) const {
    // Assert index size
    SLOW_ASSERT(index >= 0 && index < N);
    // Return current value
    return m_buffer[index];
}
```